# Consequence of using finally from performance point in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

While working on windows service that I have inherited I have come across code with try / catch and  finally.

Would be the second snippet more efficient while processing?

Consider snippet 1:

```
Try
 DoSomeLogic()
Catch Ex As Exception
      Throw New Exception("Exception: " & Ex.Message)
Finally
  ' not used
End Try
```

Consider snippet 2:

```
Try
 DoSomeLogic()
Catch Ex As Exception
      Throw New Exception("Exception: " & Ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: I would expect the compiler to not emit anything for the empty `Finally` block in the first example, so performance should be identical.  Inspect the compiled IL to see.  That said, performance questions are best answered by objectively testing the code in your environment with your data.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. Regardless of performance, since it means nothing to you, and you're not using it. Remove the finally... It's not required for a try-catch block.